# Rewriting URL in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I am new to sitecore, all my url to the pages in my project looks like the following

```
 http://domain/Inventory/Pages/AboutUs.aspx
 http://domain/Inventory/Pages/ContactUs.aspx
```

Here i need to convert all the url's to the following format

```
 http://domain/AboutUs.aspx
 http://domain/ContactUs.aspx
```

Here is my Content tree structure

```
 +Content
   +Inventory
     +Pages
       AboutUs
       ContactUs
       Home
```

Inventory and Pages are directories, these directories should not appear in my browser url

Please help me in this.

Comment: It very much depends on the rest of your content tree structure, and how many URLs you have which need the different format. Provide some more details.

Comment: Could use an Alias, but kindy hacky and mis-leading.

Comment: Given your site structure and desired URL pattern, you should be able to achieve this with some simple site configuration. Please check http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx for further information but essentially I think you just need to set your root path to "/Sitecore/Content/Inventory/Pages" and your start item to "/Home" and that will solve your problem.

Comment: Unless/until this question is reopened, there isn't too much that we can do to help you. However, I highly recommend that you download and install a new instance of Sitecore with the Example Site. Take a look at its structure, the page URLs, and the settings in the `sites/site[name="website"]` node of the `web.config` (especially the `startItem` attribute). The start item's name is not required in the URLs for any of its child pages, which is why it is typically suggested to have the "Home" item be the root instead of your "Pages" item, as this also helps with multi-site instances.

Comment: Also, don't forget to reference the [Sitecore Documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set root path and start path of your site in SiteDefination.config file under app_Config\Include. You don't need to reset content tree structure.

```
 rootPath="/sitecore/content/Inventory"
 startItem="/Pages"
```

please make sure to enable SiteDeffination.config if this is disable

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to do any URL rewriting, just configure the start item in Sitecore.

In the web.config file you will see a section called `<sites>` with a node called `<site name="website"..` this node has an attribute called `startItem`. Change it's value from the default to `/Inventory/Pages`. Note that with this setup and your current content tree you would have `hostname/home` and `hostname/AboutUs`.  If you went to `hostname/` you would be browsing the 'Pages' item which might not be what you intend?  It would be more conventional to have a structure such as

```
+Sitecore
  +Content
    +Inventory
      +Home
        +AboutUs
        +ContactUs
```